# Laravel forward to 404 error page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0. Is there any way to forward to default 404 page error if the user wrong url. I want to forward all the time if the user entered wrong url in my project.

Comment: what do you mean by default 404 page? what does the page shows when you input an incorrect url right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `resources/views/errors` folder make sure you have a `404.blade.php` file and if that is not there then create it and put something in this file.

Basically, if that `404` file is not present there then You'll see an error like this:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>
> NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 901:
>
> ....

.

Sepending on your environment setup. FYI, in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` file the handler method `handles/catches` the errors. So check it, you may customize it, for example:

```
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

// You can use/catch this but basically this is not included in Handler
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    //...

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // Customize it, extra code
        if ($e instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException) {
            return response(view('errors.403'), 403);
        }
        
        // The method has only this line by default
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Then, make sure, the `403.blade.php` is also available in your `resources/views/errors` directory.

Comment: Shouldn't _view('error.403')_ be _view('error**s**.403')_

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.